# Ruby string indexing with variable-width encoding

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, utf-8

This question has to do with performance of fixed width (i.e. UTF-32) vs. [variable width](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding) (i.e. UTF-8) encoded strings.

**Specifically, if I have a Ruby string that has 1024 characters (not bytes, characters) and want to obtain the 1000th character, does it have to read from the beginning of the string and look at each *lead unit* to know how many bytes to next scan before it gets to the next character?**

The [wikipedia variable-width encoding page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding) does a good job of explaining this if you aren't sure what I am talking about.

I put together a benchmark test to see how long it would take to index to a particular string's character and have listed the source and results below.  Notice I used both the ***a*** and ***渥*** to make sure I had a *lead unit* situation.

```
require 'benchmark'

def my_test(encoding, character)
  str = (character * 1024).encode(encoding)
  result =  Benchmark.measure { 
    (1..1000000).each do 
      str[1000]
    end
  }
  puts "Encoding: #{encoding.ljust(10)}  Character: #{character.ljust(2)}   Seconds: #{result}"
end

my_test 'UTF-8', 'a'
my_test 'UTF-16', 'a'
my_test 'UTF-32', 'a'
my_test 'Shift_JIS', 'a'
my_test 'US-ASCII', 'a'
my_test 'IBM437', 'a'

puts "------------"

my_test 'UTF-8', '渥'
my_test 'UTF-16', '渥'
my_test 'UTF-32', '渥'
my_test 'Shift_JIS', '渥'
```

**Results:**

Note how UTF-8 beats UTF-16/32 by a hair when in *singleton* territory, but takes a lot longer when in *lead unit* territory.
[image]

Comment: You're trading storage for speed here, so the results aren't too surprising. I'd only be concerned about this if you're doing deep substrings literally millions of times in a row. The memory overhead of UTF-32 is considerable.

Comment: The typical response in the corporate world is to optimize what you can, then throw a faster machine at it to speed up what is too costly to optimize. At most places machines are cheap and programmer's time isn't.

Comment: @tadman I agree UTF-32 storage is considerably larger when dealing with US_ASCII.  In my case I am much more looking at CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) characters and many of them require 3 bytes in UTF-8 and only 2 bytes in UTF-16.  With that said, what are your thoughts on UTF-16 over UTF-8 in a RubyOnRails scenario?  I specifically say "RubyOnRails" scenario to convey the data eventually needs to make it out to the browser and the majority of a page is HTML/JavaScript/CSS (which all fit into UTF-8 singletons and thus *halve* data transmission).  Thoughts?